# MacPorts clang not using its own headers

Tags: c++, macos, clang, macports, include-path

I'm trying to get emscripten to work on OS X 10.8, see [this post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/emscripten-discuss/5Or6QIzkqf0/bZ-WiuHUeDEJ) for some related issues there. Apparently the `clang++` version shipped with Xcode is too old, so I got a recent clang 3.7.0 using MacPorts. I even told CMake to use that compiler (passing `-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++-mp-3.7` on the command line), but it still fails:

```
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/optimizer.dir/parser.cpp.o
/opt/local/bin/clang++-mp-3.7    -std=c++11 -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -O3 -DNDEBUG
  -o CMakeFiles/optimizer.dir/parser.cpp.o
  -c …/emsdk/emscripten/master/tools/optimizer/parser.cpp
In file included from …/emsdk/emscripten/master/tools/optimizer/parser.cpp:2:
In file included from …/emsdk/emscripten/master/tools/optimizer/parser.h:12:
…/emsdk/emscripten/master/tools/optimizer/istring.h:3:10: fatal error: 
      'unordered_set' file not found
#include <unordered_set>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

I can reproduce that issue by launching the compiler from the command line. In parallel build mode, sometimes it's instead complaining about `<cstdint>` for `optimizer.cpp` instead. Both these headers exist in `/opt/local/libexec/llvm-3.7/include/c++/v1/`.

- What's the canonical way to use the macports-installed version of `clang++` including its headers? Do I have to use `-I` and work out the full path, or is there something shorter?
- Can I safely do so without also switching the runtime library to the one shipped with MacPorts' clang? If not, can I somehow encode the full path of the runtime library into the created binary, either for that single library or using the `-rpath` argument to `ld` or some equivalent alternative?
  *Update:* I get unresolved symbols when I try to link stuff after specifying the include directory manually, and I don't know how to solve that. The `libcxx` package from MacPorts is empty except for a readme file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the original problem by adding `CXXFLAGS=--stdlib=libc++` to the environment. Then even the system version of clang will do everything I need. That flag works magic for MacPorts' version of `clang` as well: specifying that I get a successful build, and I can even verify (using the `-E` compiler switch) that it's using the headers I mentioned before. I'm still not certain whether there is anything to ensure that the headers match the system's version of `libc++`, though.